# How to create a link to a specific Slide in my own Slider?

Tags: javascript, html

I've build a really simple slider and I wanted to know if it possible in this one to creat e a specific link for each slide. For the moment every slide have the same link, but ideally I want to have a number added at the end to creat a link who target a specific slide like :

***[www.mydomain.fr/sliderpage#2](http://www.mydomain.fr/sliderpage#2)*** ( where #… is a number specific to a particular slide )

Here is my code :

**HTML**

```
    <div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
    <img src="thumbs/peintures/img1.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="text"><i>Babel II</i>, 2017, technique mixte sur toile, 100 × 100 cm</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
    <img src="thumbs/peintures/img2.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="text"><i>Ange musicien I</i>, 2016, technique mixte sur toile, 60 × 40 cm</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
    <img src="thumbs/peintures/img3.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="text"><i>Silence</i>, 2014, technique mixte sur toile, 140 × 140 cm</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
    <img src="thumbs/peintures/img1.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="text"><i>Oasis</i> 2014, technique mixte sur toile, 140 × 140 cm</div>
  </div>

  <img src="assets/prev.png" class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"></img>
  <img src="assets/next.png" class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"></img>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
  var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length};
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].classList.remove("active");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].classList.add("active");
  }
```

Many thanks in advance to the community ( sorry if it's a stupid question I'm really a noob can't find a way to work it out )

Comment: Btw, I found a way with a more complex slider ( in jquery ) but basically I wanted to know if it's possible by addind something to this one to keep it simple ( with not a lot a lines )

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways,

- Wrap your slides in an anchor tag and add the link directly.

```
<div class="mySlides">
    <a href="yourLink/<path>" rel="noreferrer noopener" target="_blank">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="thumbs/peintures/img1.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
      <div class="text"><i>Babel II</i>, 2017, technique mixte sur toile, 100 × 100 cm</div>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <a href="yourLink/<path>" rel="noreferrer noopener" target="_blank">
     <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
     <img src="thumbs/peintures/img2.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
     <div class="text"><i>Ange musicien I</i>, 2016, technique mixte sur toile, 60 × 40 cm</div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

- Add a click listener to your slides container and use it to open the link

```
 // add data attribute in HTML
 <div class="mySlides" data-link="<linkId>"> </div> 
 
 const container = document.querySelector('.slideshow-container');
 container.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const slide = e.target;
    const slideLink = slide.getAttribute('data-link');
    if (slideLink) {
      window.open(slideLink, '_blank');
    }
 })
```

I'd prefer the first method since it's more semantic. In the second method, you might have to loop till you reach the node with `data-` attached as click event might occur on a nested child as well.

Also, you can cache your queried DOM Elements instead of querying the whole DOM again everytime `showSlides` is called.

```
// query the DOM once and reuse them
const slides = document.querySelector(".mySlides");
const dots = document.querySelector(".dot");

let slideIndex = 1;
showSlides()
```

I misinterpreted the question. The above will just add a link to each slide. However, the question actually intends to ask -

**How to have a location hash associated with each slide ?**

- For that first, add a unique id to each slide,

```
<div class="mySlides" id="titre1">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="thumbs/peintures/img1.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
      <div class="text"><i>Babel II</i>, 2017, technique mixte sur toile, 100 × 100 cm</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides" id="titre2">
     <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
     <img src="thumbs/peintures/img2.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
     <div class="text"><i>Ange musicien I</i>, 2016, technique mixte sur toile, 60 × 40 cm</div>
  </div>
```

- Modify the `showSlides` method to update the window location whenever a slide is changed

```
function showSlides() {
 ...
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
     slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].classList.remove("active");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].classList.add("active");
  window.location.hash = slides[slideIndex-1].id;
}
```

Now, on every slide change the url will also be updated.

To show, the current slide whenever you navigate directly on say `url/#slideId`, we'd have to first get the hash fragment from the url on our script load and then update the slideIndex accordingly

```
  let slideIndex = 1;
  const slideToLoad = window.location.hash.split(1);
  const allSlides = document.querySelectorAll(".mySlides");

  if (slideToLoad) {
     for(let slide=0; slide < allSlides.length; slide++) {
         // we find the slide with the id and assign the index to slideIndex
         if(allSlides[slide].id === slideToLoad) { 
              slideIndex = slide; 
              return;
         }
     }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice ! ( be ready I'm certainly stupid ahah ) 

I've tried the first method but when I slide there is no change appear in the URL bar in chrome and if I set an hyperlink who target the "slide link" it always show the first slide + if i click on the slide it open a new tab. Do i have done your method in a wrong way or just I explain myself too badly ? 

here is a link where i've put a test : https://quentingaudry.fr/peintures.html

Comment: I think I misinterpreted your question. I've edited my answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hundred thanks ! Don't have much time to test it i the coming days but I will let you know ( thank you you for your patience and kindnes if one day you need advice about grpahic design don't hesitate )